# (R) I'm trying to reference a column in a dataframe with an if() statement to compute multiple other columns

Tags: r

This is the simplified dataset I created to illustrate my question.

[image: data]

Hello all, I'm trying to reference a column in a dataframe `Database`. My goal is to be able to reference, say, the `Weight` column and from that populate the `Risk` and `Overweight` columns. Here is what I'm trying (along with other failed code):

```
ifelse(Database[,"Weight"] >190, Database$Risk="HIGH", Database$Risk="LOW")

Error: unexpected '=' in "ifelse(Database[,"Weight"] >190, Database$Risk="
```

I have also tried doing groups of code with the `if()` command.

```
if(Database$Weight > 190) {Database$Risk="HIGH"; Database$Overweight="YES"}

Error in if (Database$Weight > 190) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(Database$Weight, 190) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
2: In if (Database$Weight > 190) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

...Which clearly I'm not doing correctly.

The ideal output of this code would resemble this:

[image: The desired dataframe.]

Comment: `Database$Risk=ifelse(Database$Weight >190, "HIGH", "LOW")`

Comment: This worked! ... but I ran into a follow up error:

    In Ops.factor(Database$Weight, 190) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

So I thought doing ` Database$Weight <- as.numeric(Database$Weight)` would fix this, but it made all of my weight values `c(1, 2, 3)`.

How do I get my original weight values and make that a numeric column?

Comment: Don't post pictures of data; paste the result of `dput(my_data)`. [Info.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610)

Comment: `Database$Risk=ifelse(as.double(as.character(Database$Weight)) >190, "HIGH", "LOW")`

Comment: Try converting the `Weight` from factor to character like this `Database$Risk=ifelse(as.character(Database$Weight) >190, "HIGH", "LOW")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can avoid `ifelse` with in place assignment using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Database)[, Risk := "LOW"][Weight > 190, Risk := "HIGH"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. I have assumed `Overweight`is also classified based on `Weight`. You can change the condition if required.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Risk=ifelse(Weight>190,"HIGH","LOW"), 
         Overweight=ifelse(Weight>190,"YES","NO"))
```